# Android 4.0.4 device - Shows no USB Devices when there are

Tags: android, usb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

```
usb_manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
HashMap<String, UsbDevice> deviceList = usb_manager.getDeviceList();
```

& deviceList.size() is 0

Am I doing something wrong? The device clearly has an USB port, but can't find it.
Can this be a permission issue?

Is there a possibility that the USB port could not be used in the SDK ?

(Android 4.0.4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a possibility that the USB port could not be used in the SDK ?

Yes. It looks as if your device supports USB OTG, but not the API. This is the case for most cheap tablets.

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#getDeviceList%28%29) clearly says :

> Returns a HashMap containing all USB devices **currently attached**

and

> Currently only host mode is supported in the public API.

And I understand you don't have anything in usb port.

Comment: UsbManager manager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
UsbAccessory[] accessoryList = manager.getAccessoryList();

This returns NULL.